# Generating unique contact % with sql

Tags: sql

I am hoping to generate unique contact %. not sure how to divide the 2. Can someone help? thanks

```
select
attached to_,
count(record),
count(distinct customer),
from table
group by 1
```

table of sample data [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Select attached_to,
       COUNT(customer) As total_contact,
       COUNT(Distinct customer) As unique_contact,
       COUNT(Distinct customer) / COUNT(customer) As '%_of_unique'
From Tbl
Group By attached_to
```

See a demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c1b199496543d64bfbae3e5ecd48b00e).

Comment: Hi, % col is showing as 0, is it rounding off?

Comment: What `DBMS` you are using?

Comment: If you are using `SQL Server`, multiply the dividend by 1.00, chek this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0a46b3e281735d76997947d6c236f667

Comment: I am using athena, i think its based off presto, the x1.00 did not work

Comment: The other solution is to cast the counts as Decimal or Double, `CAST(COUNT(Distinct customer) As Double) / CAST(COUNT(customer) As Double)`

Comment: Also you may multiply the dividend by `1e0`... `COUNT(Distinct customer) * 1e0 / COUNT(customer)`.

Comment: Ahmed, the double worked, but too many decimal places, how do i shorten to 2 decimals?

Comment: nvm, decimal (7,2) worked. thanks!